# Theming the field.tpl.php - accessing variables from a field collection

Tags: entities, theming

I've got a field template which is rendering a field collection field using the standard field.tpl.php file:

```
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
      <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?></div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
```

I want to output the a CSS class inside the div in the loop with some text which comes from a colour field inside the $item variable.

EG. I would like to access the variable such as:
**render($item['field_colour']);**
in the loop, but this obviously doesn't work.

What's the best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

In standard field.tpl files you can access your field collection items using this code:

```
foreach ($items as $k) {
  foreach ($k['entity']['field_collection_item'] as $id => $field_collection) {
    $field_collection_item = field_collection_item_load($id);
    $field_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $field_collection_item);
    $field_colour = $field_wrapper->field_colour->value();
  }
}
```

I don't know if it is a best practice to do that, but this is my way.